# How to create form to waiting connection to sql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need to create form for waiting a connection until a successful connection from MySQLClient and when a connection was successful ,This form is closed . Like this Photo.
[Waiting Conneciton Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3zhk.jpg)

I've seen use by Timer .But I can't do it

Is there anybody who can help me. Thank you very much

I already have code to try connection.But i need to show this form while connection is connecting and when connection is successful This form is closed.

```
Public Class frm_connectio_state
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
Private Sub frm_connectio_state_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        conn = New MySqlConnection(constr)
        conn.Open()
        Timer1.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Connection State: Error", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Application.Exit()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: As is you are asking for us to write the code *for* you.  Without the code you tried, we cant *help*.  Also missing a few details like if the DB a remote/web DB

Comment: I understand. I will take for you.